# jQuery Javascript Modal Popup not working in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

when I click on link "Comments" a modal popup opens up and shows content, therefore it does what it is supposed to.

Going to my issue:
In the first scenario, it happens what I want but some other code does not get implemented. In this case, I place the "@section" inside Index.cshtml and the modal popup is rendered in the middle of the page with some styling(which is what I want),  but the datatable and yadcf code above the @section does not seem to get executed(datatable filters not there for example).  I show this scenario in jpeg attached called "Wanted Modal Popup .
[image]

On the other hand, in the second scenario, if I put the @section inside the "ViewAll" view the datatable works correctly, the modal popup come up as well, but it does appear like in the first scenario.  I show this second scenario in the jpeg called "Unwanted Modal Popup".
[image]

I would like to leave the code in the ViewAll view(second scenario) as this is the one related to the modal popup.  Also, when I do that the attached error comes up.  I looked the error up and it seems there may be some incompatibility?  If so, why would it work on the index page then?
[image]

Could you please help?  I spent lots of time trying to resolve the issue but was unsuccessful.

**LAYOUT VIEW CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Helpdesk Support", "Index", "Tickets", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Nicola's Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    <script src="~/Scripts/Scripts.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("scriptsKnowledge", required: false)
    @RenderSection("modalComments", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

**INDEX.CSHTML VIEW CODE:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#firstTab">View All</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#secondTab">Add New</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#thirdTab">Knowledge</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fourthTab">IT Tasks</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="firstTab" class="tab-pane fade in active">@Html.Action("ViewAll")</div>
    <div id="secondTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("AddOrEdit")</div>
    <div id="thirdTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewAllKnowledge")</div>
    <div id="fourthTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewAllTasks")</div>
</div>



@*jQuery Datatable CSS*@
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">                @*for the visual style of the datepicker of the dtLastUpdated column*@
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">    @*For column reorder functionality*@
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css">    @*For column reorder functionality*@


@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    @*jQuery Datatable JS*@
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>                                  
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>     


    <script>
        function activatejQueryTable() {

            var table = $('#ticketTable').DataTable({
                rowReorder: { selector: 'tr' }, 
                colReorder: true,               
                "stateSave": true,              
                "stateDuration": 0,             
                "autoWidth": false,             
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "width": "40px", "targets": 0, "visible": true },     
                    { "width": "150px", "targets": 1, "visible": true },    //dtLastUpdated
                    { "width": "250px", "targets": 2, "visible": true },    //vcSubject
                    { "width": "150px", "targets": 3, "visible": true },    //vcFrom
                    { "width": "53px", "targets": 4, "visible": true },     //vcPriority
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 5, "visible": true },     //vcAssignedTo
                    { "width": "53px", "targets": 6, "visible": true },     //vcStatus
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 7, "visible": true },     //vcRequestType
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 8, "visible": true },     //vcLocation
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 9, "visible": true },     //vcCategory
                    { "width": "90px", "targets": 10, "visible": true },    //dtAnticipatedCompletion
                    { "width": "50px", "targets": 11, "visible": true }     //edit and delete buttons
                ],

                //Create the dropdowns
                responsive: true,
               "bAutoWidth": false,            
                initComplete: function () {

                    this.api().columns([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).every(function () {      //this is to put a dropdown just for some columns
                        var column = this;

                        var select = $('<select class="myDropdown"><option value=""></option></select>')

                            .appendTo($("#filters").find("th").eq(column.index()))
                            .on('change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                                column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                            })
                            .on('click', function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();                                //this event handler catches the click and then prevents propagation. Without this, the sort of the column happens every time you click on the dropdown
                            });

                        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                            $(select).append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                        });
                    });
                }
                //End of create dropdowns
            });



            //Datepicker for dtLastUpdated column, which has id="datepicker" and class="datepicker"
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                maxDate: 0,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    table.draw();
                }
            }).on("input change", function () {

                filterGlobal();
            });
        }
        //});


        //Also part of Datepicker for dtLastUpdated column
        function filterGlobal() {
            $('#ticketTable').DataTable().search(
                $(".datepicker").val()
            ).draw();
        }



        $(function () {
            activatejQueryTable();
        });     

    </script>
}



@section scriptsKnowledge
        {
    <script src="~/DataTables/datatables.js"></script>
    @*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yadcf/0.9.3/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.js" integrity="sha256-nX2mPo5tTUWsDUalF2TgsIn8mKkjzrkc/XMHbfpRfF0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Yadcf/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js"></script>

    <script>
        function yadcfTable() {
            var oTable;
            oTable = $('#knowledgeTable').DataTable({
                stateSave: true
            });

            yadcf.init(oTable, [
                { column_number: 0 }]);
        }

        $(function () {
            yadcfTable();
        });
    </script>
}



@section modalComments
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showComments() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                title: "View Details"
            });
            $("#ticketTable .details").click(function () {
                var ticketNum = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Tickets/ViewComments",
                    data: '{ticketNum: "' + ticketNum + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#dialog').html(response);
                        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        };

        $(function () {
            showComments();
        });
    </script>
}
```

**VIEWALL.CSHTML VIEW CODE:**

```
@model IEnumerable<HelpDeskSupport.Models.Ticket>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewAll";
    //Layout = null;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@section modalComments
    {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showComments() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                title: "View Details"
            });
            $("#ticketTable .details").click(function () {
                var ticketNum = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Tickets/ViewComments",
                    data: '{ticketNum: "' + ticketNum + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#dialog').html(response);
                        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        };

        $(function () {
            showComments();
        });
    </script>
}



@*<head>*@
@*<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@
@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>*@
@*<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>*@
@*<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@
@*<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                title: "View Details"
            });
            $("#ticketTable .details").click(function () {
                var ticketNum = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Tickets/ViewComments",
                    data: '{ticketNum: "' + ticketNum + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#dialog').html(response);
                        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>*@
@*</head>*@



@*<input type="submit" value="Clear Filters" id="filterBtn" class="bg-info" onclick="cleanFilters()">*@
<button type="button" onclick="cleanFilters()" value="Clear Filters" id="filterBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Clear Filters / Reset</button>


@*jQuery Datatable (and could also be for ThemeRoller*@
<table class="display table table-striped table-bordered" id="ticketTable" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr id="filters">
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.iNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dtLastUpdated)
                <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker">    @*readonly="readonly"*@
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcSubject)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcFrom)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcPriority)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcAssignedTo)
            </th>
            @*<th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dtAssignedDate)
                </th>*@
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcStatus)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcRequestType)
            </th>
            @*<th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcBody)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dtDateSubmitted)
                </th>*@
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcLocation)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vcCategory)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dtAnticipatedCompletion)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.iNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dtLastUpdated)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcSubject)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcFrom)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcPriority)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcAssignedTo)
                </td>
                @*<td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dtAssignedDate)
                    </td>*@
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcStatus)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcRequestType)
                </td>
                @*<td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcBody)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dtDateSubmitted)
                    </td>*@
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcLocation)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vcCategory)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dtAnticipatedCompletion)
                </td>
                <td>
                   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="Edit('@Url.Action("EditOneRecord", "Tickets", new { id = item.iNumber })')"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="Delete('@Url.Action("Delete", "Tickets", new { id = item.iNumber })')"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a class="details" href="javascript:;">Comments</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have presented it is difficult to understand what version of jquery you want to use, but the error message shows that when the error happens you are using jquery 3.4.1.

Per https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker/issues/132, you get this error if you combine Jquery 3.x with JqueryUI 1.11.  The fix here is to upgrade to JqueryUI 1.12.

You might want to get rid of all of the commented-out stuff and re-post your question; it is extremely difficult to notice which parts of the code are commented out, and that will make it hard for others to suggest answers. You seem to be undecided between using two different versions of Jquery (1.7.2 vs. 3.4.1), that is probably a source of problems for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  The problem was that I had 1.11.4 jquery-ui instead of a newer one.  I found out that Jquery 3.4.1 does not work with jquery 1.11.4 but it would with 1.12.0.  Thank you very much for your help.